# Why go writes 000/s instead of string?

Tags: go

For some reasons go encodes the string like bytes and I'm wondering if it's a go bug. See the code below:

```
ip, _, err := net.ParseCIDR(cidr)
if err!=nil{
     log.Panicf("can't parse cidr %s, err was %v", cidr, err)
}

type Ip struct{
     Ip string
}

ips := string(ip)
j:= Ip{
     Ip: ips,
}
b, err := json.Marshal(j)
if err != nil {
     log.Printf("error:", err)
}

fmt.Fprintln(w, string(b))
```

It prints:

```
{"Ip":"\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u0007+"}
```

I'm running Go from epel repository ( redhat ). I also made a snippet which returns similar results.

[Play it for me!](http://play.golang.org/p/JbbbfK3whZ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you are treating a sequence of IP address bytes as a raw string.

The `net.IP` value returned by `net.ParseCIDR` has a `.String()` method you should call, instead of doing `string(ip)`.

Try [this](http://play.golang.org/p/xG3hVV2SP-) instead:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    cidr := "172.162.21.84/32"

    ip, _, err := net.ParseCIDR(cidr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicf("can't parse cidr %s, err was %v", cidr, err)
    }

    type Ip struct {
        Ip string
    }

    fmt.Printf("%T: %v\n", ip, ip)

    j := Ip{
        Ip: ip.String(),
    }

    b, err := json.Marshal(j)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error:", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

Comment: How was I supposed to know that ? On goDoc I can see only  the type IP is is  []byte so I assumed it's just a slice of bytes.

Comment: It is a slice of bytes. But the bytes are the literal IP address octets. A byte value `255` does not print as a literal "255" string. That string would consist of 3 bytes for the ascii characters '2', '5' and '5' respectively.